# Timer that stops once submit is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I created a couple inputs that feed into a JavaScript command to create custom sentences. Whatever the user inputs or selects is added to a sentence framework. When the user selects submit, the sentence is created in a textarea.

I want to add a timer to my app that starts when the user starts typing in the first input field and stops when the user hits submit. This timer would be visible to the user. How would I go about creating that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Hi</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
  .chosen-select {width:200px}
 </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";

    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();
    }

    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;

            var input3 = $('#z3').val();
            console.log(input3);

            var input3Formatted = "";
            if(input3.length==1){
              // Only one value...
              input3Formatted = input3[0];
            }
            if(input3.length==2){
              // Two values... Just add and "and"
              input3Formatted = input3[0]+" and "+input3[1];
            }
            if(input3.length>2){
              // more than 2 values...
              for(i=0;i<input3.length-1;i++){
                input3Formatted += input3[i]+", ";
              }
              input3Formatted += "and "+input3[input3.length-1];
            }



            const input5 = "It has minor curb rash on the "+input3Formatted+"."
            const input7 = document.getElementById("z5").value;




      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "This is my " +input1+ ". It is in good condition.The vehicle's rims have curb rash. "+input5+" The "+input1+"'s color is "+input7+"."

    }

  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 4
    })
});
</script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <select data-placeholder="Minor Curb Rash" name="minorrash" multiple class="chosen-select" id="z3">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="front left rim">Front Left Rim</option>
              <option value="back left rim">Back Left Rim</option>
              <option value="front right rim">Front Right Rim</option>
              <option value="back right rim">Back Right Rim</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="z5" placeholder="Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>
    <p></p>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I saw the same code in a previous question this week. Look for something like [FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/) and try someting by yourself first. As is now, your question is a "code request".

Answer (score 1):

Add a div to your HTML to display the number of elapsed seconds.

On keydown into your input, trigger a `setTimeout()` with a callback that updates the elapsed, and on submit use `clearTimeout()` to stop the timer.

For more, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout